# Android move and scale custom animation

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to create my own custom animation that will move and scale the view.

```
public class MoveAndSizeAnimation extends Animation implements Animation.AnimationListener{

View view;
float fromX;
float fromY;
float fromWidth;
float fromHeight;
float toX;
float toY;
float toWidth;
float toHeight;

public MoveAndSizeAnimation(View v, float toX, float toY, float toWidth, float toHeight, int duration) {
    this.view = v;
    this.toX = toX;
    this.toY = toY;
    this.toWidth = toWidth;
    this.toHeight = toHeight;

    fromX = v.getX();
    fromY = v.getY();
    fromWidth = v.getWidth();
    fromHeight = v.getHeight();

    this.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    setDuration(duration);
}



@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {

    float newX = fromX + (toX - fromX) * interpolatedTime;
    float newY = fromY + (toY - fromY) * interpolatedTime;
    float newWidth = fromWidth + (toWidth - fromWidth) * interpolatedTime;
    float newHeight = fromHeight + (toHeight - fromHeight) * interpolatedTime;
    float scaledWidth = newWidth / fromWidth;
    float scaledHeight = newHeight / fromHeight;

    view.setX(newX);
    view.setY(newY);

    view.requestLayout();

}

@Override
public boolean willChangeBounds() {
    return false;
}}
```

The moving animation is ok but can't get the scaling right.
I've tried to set the view layoutParams but it really changed the view width and height. I want only to scale.

Can anyone help?

or how can I see how the ScaleAnimation class provided by Android works?

Answer (score 0):

ok so the answer is to use scaleX and scaleY and don't forget to set the setPivotX(0.5f) and setPivotY(0.5f).. that's it..